# Добавить элемент массива в файл

Tags: php

нужно в массив из файла list.php добавить запись по ключу

list.php

```
   return [
        'authorize' => [
            'account/profile',
            'account/settings',
        ],
        'guest' => [
            'account/register',
            'account/login',
            'admin/login',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'admin/main',
        ],
    ];
```

Нужно к примеру по ключу **'admin'** добавить еще одно значение **'admin/settings',**

```
class Settings {

    static $cfg = null;

    public static function load(){
        static::$cfg = include "file.php";
        foreach(static::$cfg as $k => $v){
            if(!defined($k)){
                define($k, $v);
            }
        }
    }

    public static function set($key, $value){
        static::$cfg[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function save(){
        $content = "<?php".PHP_EOL."\treturn\t".var_export(static::$cfg, true);

        file_put_contents("file.php", $content);
    }
}
Settings::load();
Settings::set('admin', 'admin/settings'); 
Settings::save();
```

---

Как сделать:

1. что бы скрипт добавлял запись по ключу
2. не удалял в конце **;**

---

1. что бы верно работало в методе set должно быть так:

static::$cfg[$key][] = $value;

2. что бы не удаляло ; (точку из запятой) в конце массива, нужно:

file_put_contents("file.php", $content.";");

Comment: метод `set` тут делает то что от него по названию требуется. добавление в массив реализуйте в методе `append`.

Comment: @teran, от переименования методов по другому оно не заработает

Comment: я где-то написал, что его надо переименовать? я написал, что `set` не трогайте, добавьте новый метод. вы то понятно ленивы, чтобы этим заниматься, но может кто-то решит вам тут помочь, для них коммент

Comment: Добавление элемента в массив: `$array[] = $element;`

Comment: @u_mulder, в массиве есть несколько других массивов lisp.php, нужно выбрать конкретный и в него добавить

Comment: Ну раз совсем уж лень разбираться `static::$cfg[$key][] = $value;`

Comment: @u_mulder, спасибо, добавление работает, но саму структуру почему меняет и удаляет точку из запятой в конце?

Comment: @u_mulder, сайт работает с такой структурой так же, но почему удаляет точку из запятой?

Comment: "удаляет" и "не записывает" это несколько разные вещи. вы вообще в состоянии среди этого найти одну строку кода, которая формирует запись в файл, и попытаться в ней найти свою точку с запятой?

Comment: @teran, прежде чем минусовать нужно читать вопрос внимательно, по пунктам разделил суть вопроса, который кстати решен и закрыт

Comment: я довольно внимательно прочитал, была бы возможность, то за вопросы "допишите за меня точку с запятой в строку"  я бы ставил по 2 минуса.  Когда вопрос решен и закрыт надо публиковать свой ответ и принимать его, а не вносить правки в вопрос.

Comment: @teran, если вы не разобрались где нужно дописывать ";" , это не повод ставить другим минус, а подтянуть свою же квалификацию

Comment: Здесь никто не обязан разбираться в чем-либо и подтягивать свою квалификацию. Минусы тебе ставят за то, что ты сам ни в чем не попытался разобраться самостоятельно (и тем самым "подтянуть квалификацию") до  того как задать вопрос. И @teran прав - если ты свой вопрос решил - то размести на него ответ, а не правь исходное сообщение.

Comment: @u_mulder, покажи мне, где я написал что мне кто то обязан? если я правильно понимаю это форум на котором помогают разобрать ту или иную ситуацию. Я ведь не ставлю минуса другим участникам, только потому что не знаю ответа на их вопрос, если здесь так принято, то вопросов нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вам следующий вариант для решение данной проблемы:

Хранить массив (я так понял что вы с MVC боритесь) в файле list.php в JSON формате. Если потребуется получить данные или записать воспользуйтесь функциями ниже:

**Получить массив из файла list.php**

```
function get_list ($path) {
    if (!file_exists($path) return false;
    $json = file_get_contents($path);
    return json_decode($json, true);
}
```

**Записать измененный массив в libs.php**

```
function set_list ($path, $array) {
    file_put_content($path, json_encode($array));
}
```

Comment: Вопрос уже решен, а разницы между массивом в файле php и json не вижу